# Write variables to a file

Tags: python-3.x

I can print my variables like this.

```
print(var1, var2, var3)
```

How can I write these same variables to a file?

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write(????)
```

Comment: `f.write('{} {} {}'.format(var1, var2, var3)')`?

Comment: Can I add a separator like sep=',' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python 3, You can simply add a `file=yourfile` argument at the end of print command.

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
print(var1, var2, var3, file=f)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do directly with `print` function but the problem is that the file will be still opened. A better approach is to use a context manager just like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(var1, var2, var3, file=f)

# Check if file is closed
print(f.closed) # True
```

You can read more about context managers [here](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/)